# How to handle SweetAlert confirmation button using asp:button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, onclick, sweetalert2

I am using js alert for delete confirmation but i would like to use SweetAlert2 for new confirmations. I just want to know how can i use SweetAlert2 confirmation alert and handle confirm button on asp.net webform.

**Here is button:**

```
<asp:Button ID="deleteBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="deleteBtn_Click" />
```

**Code Behind:** (Working JS)

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  deleteBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('are you sure');");
}
```

I found a solution for displaying basic message with SweetAlert2:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
    {
      deleteBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return swal('are you sure?');");
    }
```

Ask to the user if you want to delete record:

```
   if(!IsPostBack)
        {
          deleteBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return swal({title:'are you sure?', buttons:{confirm:{text:'i am sure'}, cancel{text:'cancel'}});");
        }
```

---

How can we handle confirmation button from code-behind? How can we use cancel button? I can delete a record even if i can click on cancel button.

Comment: Define "Not Working"

Comment: I am using sweetalert for showing result in popup now but i would like to use sweetalert2 onclick event for confirmation. When i changed my code with swal.fire, it doesn't show popup but deletion was successful.

Comment: Okay, let me formulate my question in another way: what error do you receive?

Comment: I get an error named "swal is not defined" and i changed "swal.fire" with "swal" and it start to show messages. This was the just messagebox, i wonder to know how can i handle confirm button?